# returning a value from an external javascript

Tags: javascript, return, external

I seem to have a problem with "return"ing values from an external script to the calling html.

Please have a look at https://www.pe-ling.nl/chincal.htm
The table at the top should contain dates.
In Chrome it works OK (dates are shown), however in IE  and Safari is does not (no dates shown).

The external javascript:

```
function SeizoenWissel() {
// Datum in feb, mei, aug, nov + nieuwjaar + winterzonnewemde
var jaar = new Date().getFullYear();
var maand = new Date().getMonth();
var dag = new Date().getDate();

//correctie maandnrs van 0-11 naar 1-12
maand = maand +1;
feb = 0; mei = 0; aug = 0; nov = 0
if (jaar == 2017) {feb = 3; mei = 5; aug = 7; nov = 7; nwjaar = '28 jan'; wzw = 21};
if (jaar == 2018) {feb = 4; mei = 5; aug = 7; nov = 7; nwjaar = '16 febr'; wzw = 21};
if (jaar == 2019) {feb = 4; mei = 6; aug = 8; nov = 8; nwjaar = '5 febr'; wzw = 22};

return{jaar, maand, dag, feb, mei, aug, nov, nwjaar, wzw};
}
```

HTML file
in the header

```
<SCRIPT src="includes/p-chincal.js" LANGUAGE="JavaScript"></SCRIPT>
```

in the body

```
<script>
x = SeizoenWissel();
jaar = x.jaar; 
feb = x.feb; mei = x.mei; aug = x.aug; nov = x.nov; nwjaar = x.nwjaar; wzw = x.wzw;
d = x.dag; m = x.maand;
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
document.write(feb + ' februari')
</script>

<script>
document.write(mei + ' mei')
</script>
```

somehow in Chrome this works OK, but not in IE/Safari

html file may be found: /chincal.htm

js file may be found:   /includes/p-chincal.js

advice is welcome

Best regards
Jan

Comment: Your return statement creates an object literal with [property value shorthand](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/#property-value-shorthand), something that not all browsers support.

Comment: Oh yes!  :-) The dates are shown. Thanks!

Comment: @JanK, also that's not a forum :)

Comment: @iehrlich - Wrong choice of words, sorry for that